# Package unicode_util_compat-0.3.1 not found; Uncaught error in rebar_core

Tags: erlang, elixir, rebar

I received an error `Package unicode_util_compat-0.3.1 not found; Updating package registry; Uncaught error in rebar_core` error in running mix deps.compile. Based on https://hex.pm/packages/unicode_util_compat description, it appears that unicode_util_compat doesn’t support Erlang 20 which I’m on. Is there anything I can do to get mix deps.compile to work without downgrading to Erlang 19?

[image]

The console output with DEBUG=1 is as follows

```
===> Compiling unicode_util_compat
===> run_hooks("e:/Data/elixir-stuff/fin_reporting/deps/unicode_util_compat", pr
e_hooks, compile) -> no hooks defined

===> run_hooks("e:/Data/elixir-stuff/fin_reporting/deps/unicode_util_compat", pr
e_hooks, erlc_compile) -> no hooks defined

===> erlopts [debug_info,debug_info,{d,'OTP20'}]
===> files to compile ["e:/Data/elixir-stuff/fin_reporting/deps/unicode_util_com
pat/src/unicode_util_compat.erl"]
===>      Compiled unicode_util_compat.erl
===> run_hooks("e:/Data/elixir-stuff/fin_reporting/deps/unicode_util_compat", po
st_hooks, erlc_compile) -> no hooks defined

===> run_hooks("e:/Data/elixir-stuff/fin_reporting/deps/unicode_util_compat", pr
e_hooks, app_compile) -> no hooks defined

===> run_hooks("e:/Data/elixir-stuff/fin_reporting/deps/unicode_util_compat", po
st_hooks, app_compile) -> no hooks defined

===> run_hooks("e:/Data/elixir-stuff/fin_reporting/deps/unicode_util_compat", po
st_hooks, compile) -> no hooks defined

===> Expanded command sequence to be run: []
===> Expanded command sequence to be run: [{default,app_discovery},
                                           {bare,compile}]
===> Package unicode_util_compat-0.3.1 not found. Fetching registry updates and
trying again...
===> Updating package registry...
===> Fetching registry from "https://repo.hex.pm:443/registry.ets.gz?"
===> Uncaught error in rebar_core. Run with DEBUG=1 to see stacktrace or consult
 rebar3.crashdump
===> Uncaught error: {badmatch,
                         {error,{rebar_prv_update,package_index_download}}}
===> Stack trace to the error location:
[{rebar_packages,handle_missing_package,3,
                 [{file,"/home/tristan/Devel/rebar3/_build/default/lib/rebar/src
/rebar_packages.erl"},
                  {line,85}]},
 {rebar_app_utils,update_source,3,
                  [{file,"/home/tristan/Devel/rebar3/_build/default/lib/rebar/sr
c/rebar_app_utils.erl"},
                   {line,262}]},
 {rebar_app_utils,dep_to_app,7,
                  [{file,"/home/tristan/Devel/rebar3/_build/default/lib/rebar/sr
c/rebar_app_utils.erl"},
                   {line,228}]},
 {rebar_app_utils,'-parse_deps/6-lc$^0/1-0-',6,
                  [{file,"/home/tristan/Devel/rebar3/_build/default/lib/rebar/sr
c/rebar_app_utils.erl"},
                   {line,129}]},
 {rebar_app_discover,'-do/2-fun-0-',3,
                     [{file,"/home/tristan/Devel/rebar3/_build/default/lib/rebar
/src/rebar_app_discover.erl"},
                      {line,41}]},
 {lists,foldl,3,[{file,"lists.erl"},{line,1263}]},
 {rebar_app_discover,do,2,
                     [{file,"/home/tristan/Devel/rebar3/_build/default/lib/rebar
/src/rebar_app_discover.erl"},
                      {line,37}]},
 {rebar_prv_app_discovery,do,1,
                          [{file,"/home/tristan/Devel/rebar3/_build/default/lib/
rebar/src/rebar_prv_app_discovery.erl"},
                           {line,38}]}]
===> When submitting a bug report, please include the output of `rebar3 report "
your command"`
** (Mix) Could not compile dependency :idna, "escript.exe "c:/Users/I805649/.mix
/rebar3" bare compile --paths "e:/Data/elixir-stuff/fin_reporting/_build/dev/lib
/*/ebin"" command failed. You can recompile this dependency with "mix deps.compi
le idna", update it with "mix deps.update idna" or clean it with "mix deps.clean
 idna"
```

Comment: The "for Erlang < 20" means this package adds `unicode_util` for Erlang < 20 since Erlang 20 includes that module already. Can you try running this with `DEBUG` set to `1` and post the output? (In *nix, that would be `DEBUG=1 mix deps.compile --all`, not sure about Windows.)

Comment: Wow, I would have never guessed that is what the < sign means. Thanks. I will try to get the debug message and post it here.

Comment: Please see the stacktrace added to the above. Thanks.

Comment: Reinstalling rebar3 from github fixed the issue. Thanks Dogbert.

Answer (score 1):

You can also update/reinstall rebar (and rebar3) locally via `mix local.rebar`